# When to use `unSubscribeOn` in rxjava

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

I have been using RxJava for a while. I make use of the `subscribeOn` and `observeOn` operators to manage threads. I use `subscribeOn` to start observable emission in an `io` or `computation` thread, and I observe the result in main thread using `observeOn(AndroidSchedluers.mainThread())`

Throughout my app, a stream usually looks like this

```
compositeDisposable.add(observable()
            .flatMap(result-> { // do something })
            .map(result -> // doSomething)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()))
            .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<Object>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onNext(Object o) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(Throwable e) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onComplete() {

                            }
                        }));
```

As you can see, the Observer I'm adding to a `CompositeDisposable` so that, in case my activity or fragment goes out of scope during the observable doing something in the background thread, I can safely disconnect the observer from the chain to avoid any memory leaks. Pretty straightforward.

But in some of the examples, I have seen the `unSubscribeOn` operator used to make the unsubscription to be in a specific thread. I am kind of not understanding the actual need for that. Infact I have never used that, I have not been ended up any memory leaks either by not using it.

Is it something we need to use always? Or can anyone explain some use cases where we need to go for `unSubscribeOn`?

I have referred the official documentation and some of the examples as well, but kind of not digesting it. If someone could explain with a sample, it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If you set the subscribeOn and observeOn and no unsubscribeOn , the typical behaviour is, unsubscribe happens in the same thread as observeOn.

If you set only the subscribeOn, and no observeOn ,no unSubscribeOn, the unsubscribe happens at subscribeOn thread.

The unSubscribeOn will be useful, if you want to run a long running task during unsubscribe.

You can run the above tests using **Thread.currentThread().getId()** for each scenarios.

Comment: I understood the concept whatever you have mentioned, while reading the documentation itself. Can you provide a real world scenario where we need to go for unSubscribeOn. _**to run a long running task during unsubscribe**_ Any example for this?? Because I have never come across such a scenario. can you suggest usual use cases for that?

Comment: Not just a long-running task. Any task that makes a network call cannot run on the `mainThread`. If you try to unsubscribe from the observable from the `mainThread`, and it makes a network call, no matter how brief, you will get an exception.

Comment: You mean from the observables which Are having a Network call , we should do unSubscribe in background thread?

Comment: Can anyone please explain what all things happen internally when an unSubscribe is performed? Is it just removing the observer reference from the observable? Or more than that?

Comment: Actually the statement in second paragraph is wrong. Unsubscribe does not happen on `subscribeOn` thread, at least in RxJava 2. We need to use `unsubscribeOn` to move disposing to a thread other than the calling thread.